# Pass onfocus on onmouseenter event in javascript

Tags: javascript, onfocus

I have a requirement where when a user hover through a section, the section gets active without clicking the mouse button.

Example: 2 text boxes open side by side on a web browser, user hovers on one of them and start wirting startight away without even clicking the mouse.

Can we do this by calling onfocus() when the mouse does a onmouseenter()?

Comment: Yes, it should be possible. Did you try it? If so, what didn't work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this code:

```
$("input").mouseenter(function() {
    $(this).focus();
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/zfggtf3b/